# How can mages conquer the world

Tags: magic, society, military

So the socity of mages is tired of living in secret and want to transform the world into thier play ground where they can use and abuse magic in the open.

To accomplish this they must conquer the world. Not simply control it from the shadows but truly conquer and ruel it.

The main barrier

1. Population: there are less then a 100 thousand total mages.
2. Monder weaponry has advanced to the point that they can surpass the destructive potential of mages.

Could they still be able to take over the world?

Magic system details:
Limitations while wide scale magic dose exist it requires thousands of mages working together.

This means most spells are limited to point and shoot weapons that can only effect one object at a time and limited to line of sight.

Types of spells:

Transformation: change one thing to another.

Transportation: teleporting.

Elemental control: (heat, liquid, earth, air)

Divination:limited view of the future.

Telekinesis

Temporal control: only up to a minute

Necromancy: construction of undead events.
Mental: mindcontrol and mental manipulation spells.
And summoning: which alows for you to bring monstrous animals from other worlds to this one.

Comment: How can mages conquer the world is about the actions of your characters, not a good fit for this community. Could they conquer the world is a matter of your story, again, not a good fit for this community

Comment: You can ask for strategic guidance  to increase the winning odds with the tools at disposal in generic yet specific circumstances, but the whole conquest? Too chaotic and unpredictable (aka. story dependent), and really too broad. How can a nation conquer even a part of the world is worth its own novel, and in fact is the premise of some stories out there ^^.

Comment: Sorry, this sounds like a "please write my story for me" request. I could write a hundred different books on this premise. I would start by identifying how "take over the world" is different from "control from the shadows." Is this just a matter of letting the everyman know that the wizards are in charge, or do you have to make them all bow down to you and do your bidding?

Comment: Tortliena thank you for the feed back

Comment: @RobertRapplean is right. You're asking us to provide what is literally the core plot element of your story. Remember from the [help/on-topic] that we'll help you build your world (rules that are independent of all stories) but we will not help you tell your story. (Storybuilding violates the [help/dont-ask] expectation that there must be the reasonable expectation of one right answer. There is no wrong answer to this question.)

Answer (score 1):

Start by ruling from the shadows. Find wealthy and powerful people. For example Phoebe Buffet:

[image]

Phoebe is "an American business magnate, investor, and philanthropist, and the chairman and CEO of Berkshire Hathaway."

Knock on her front door. When she answers use your:

> Mental: mindcontrol and mental manipulation spells.

to make her your friend. Hang out with Phoebe for a few years. Learn her habits and her bank account details. Then use your:

> Transformation: change one thing to another.

To turn her into a frog. Put the frog in a nice terrarium and put it on a  shelf. Next turn yourself into Phoebe. Now all her money and influence is yours!

Repeat the process for hundreds of influential people around the world. CEOS of large companies, politicians, army generals. Everyone who gives the orders.

Once all the order-givers are replaced with mages, simply give the order that the mages are now in charge. Everyone else gets sent to toil in the mana mines.

Image is Phoebe Buffay from the 1990s sitcom [Friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friends).

Comment: I think we missed one of the OP's conditions, "Not simply control it from the shadows but truly conquer and rule it." Also, who's Phoebe? I can only find that quotation you use to describe her on three websites and they all refer to Warren Buffet. Warren's children are named Howard, Peter, and Susan. A TinEye check on the image suggests it might be the actress who played Phoebe Buffay on the TV show "Friends." (Remember that we expect credit for images you didn't create...)

Comment: @JBH the image is indeed of Phoebe from the TV shot Friends. I assume Daron used it to just illustrate the example. The essence is "Find rich and powerful person, take over their life". I read the rest as just giving a name for the person and then also adding a face to the name, so it doesn't need to be a literal faceless entity talked about. Otherwise the post just reads too dry "Find person. Befriend person. Turn person into frog." So, it doesn't really have to be any specific person, it only serves for illustration. And I suppose Phoebe Buffay/Buffet is a small pun.

Comment: @VLAZ I am always getting those two mixed up. . . .

Comment: @JBH The image is indeed Phoebe from Friends. Image description included at the bottom. The "truly conquer and rule it." part comes after you have replaced all the leaders of the world. At that point you come out of the shadows and make it so the mages are in charge.

Answer (score 0):

### Exploit the subjugation of the political by the economic

The world is supposed to be ruled by governments, but increasingly it is *de facto* ruled by super-wealthy individuals who are not part of any government (and are actually opposed to government *per se* except as a "neutral" enforcer of contract and property law). These wealthy people have spent decades weakening governments and political systems, in part by capturing or replacing parts of those systems with their own creatures.

Very importantly, these cultivated weaknesses can be exploited by *anybody* who has the right tools, and the right tool is massive amounts of money. (These weakness all require massive expenditures; they simply do not respond to small amounts of money.) Money is the instrumental goal *par excellence,* because people with lots of money want it that way, and because it's very hard to fake. Magic is a loophole they have not closed, and may not be able to close.

Your mages have multiple paths to amass staggering amounts of wealth:

- They can use magic to rob today's "legitimately" super-wealthy, perhaps as described by Daron. Simply *steal* the keys that unlock the government's back door.
- They can use magic to provide products or services that are only feasible when the laws of physics can be broken (which is what a lot of magic does, particularly elemental control), which should make it easy to dominate the market and vacuum up all the money in that industry. Since it seems like every industry these days is a "billion-dollar" industry, if do this a few times you can easily become one of the top 50 wealthiest living humans.
- Mages will probably have a pretty easy time stealing valuable stuff that can be sold for exorbitant prices. Industrial espionage would be at the top of my list, the idea being to threaten to sell the victim's valuable stuff to a competitor. And if the victim won't buy, the competitor might.

---

No matter what: kill all the non-mage elite. The people who rule the world today will not be happy after the mages have seized power, and they will be well-positioned to mount a resistance. A pine box is the only thing that will stop them trying to take back the world they feel entitled to.

The people who rule the world are hard to get to if you have to abide by the laws of physics. It's also hard to get away with assassination, since playing by the laws of physics tends to result in a trail of evidence that can be followed by any sufficiently dogged investigator. Magic can solve all of these problems, even if all it does is eliminate the need to sneak a weapon through security.

Murder may not be the best way achieve power, but once you are there, it is a very prudent first step to entrench your power. Take it from the ruling elite: "entrenchment" is the name of the game.